# reset the interval when button is clicked

Tags: jquery

I have the following jquery...

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $('ul li').on('click', function(){
    $('ul li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active'); 
  }); //end click
  $('ul li').first().click();
  setInterval(function(){
    var nextli = $('ul li').filter('.active').removeClass('active').next();
    nextli.addClass('active');
    if(!nextli.length){
      nextli = $('ul li').first();
    }   
    nextli.addClass('active');
  }, 5000); //end set interval
}); //end document ready
```

I have set the interval for 5 seconds so if I click to the list just after waiting for 4 seconds that obviously be activated next list just after 1 second. So I need to reset the interval. I've tried clearInterval and a lot I tried but couldn't succeed. Any help would be appriciated.

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aKUHR/6/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to stop and start the interval in the click handler. The `setInterval` method returns a handle that you can use to stop it.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

  var timer = null;

  $('ul li').on('click', function(){
    $('ul li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    if (timer != null) {
      window.clearInterval(timer);
    }
    timer = window.setInterval(function(){
      var nextli = $('ul li').filter('.active').removeClass('active').next();
      if (!nextli.length){
        nextli = $('ul li').first();
      }
      nextli.addClass('active');
    }, 5000);
  });
  $('ul li').first().click();

});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/aKUHR/10/